# Unable to restore ubuntu grub or reinstall ubuntu after installing windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I was dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 then I installed windows 8.1, but now I can't login to Ubuntu. I tried boot repair to restore the grub. After clicking on recommended repair it shows that the repair is successful but after restarting my PC it goes directly to Windows 8.1.

I also tried using a live cd of Ubuntu 13.10 opened the terminal and tried typing fdisk -l but it does not show any partition not even windows.

When I try to install the Ubuntu again it shows me only 1 option to erase the whole disk and then install. There is no option of installing alongside Windows.

Please help me how to get the grub again or reinstalling it alongside windows 8.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: boot ubuntu live cd and upload gparted screenshot,i will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

Sorry I am unable to attach the screenshot as I need at least 10 reputation to post image.

However, when I open gparted it shows that my whole disk as unallocated.

Thank you